# spawn/summon command for sever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Curious if there is a way to disable random mob spawning yet still allow you to use the /summon command? A plugin recommendation would work as well if anyone knows of one.

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic here. But the wiki or a quick Google search can already answer your question: `gamerule doMobSpawning false`

Comment: that still disables summoning.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Are you sure you're playing on a Vanilla server?

Answer (score 1):

See **server.properties**, look for `spawn-monsters=true`
No plugin needed.

Cheers!